# Is there any Wordpress alternative to Book module of Drupal?

Tags: posts, pages, customization

Wordpress can be used as CMS. So, I think I can switch from Drupal to Wordpress.
I'm looking for a book module alternative for creating structured document.
If you don't know about Book module of Drupal, follow this link: http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/book
It simply put all page links in navigational block maintaining the hierarchical sequence. Plus, it displays next & previous pages in sequence at bottom with their respective links. The book module documentation at previous link is also an example of Book module page.

Answer (score 2):

With a hierarchical post type, a plugin would just need to write the navigation part. All the rest is already there.

Comment: Navigational part is the main thing. Plus, what about navigational links at bottom? Book module does it automatically..

Comment: Yes, the navigation links at the bottom is what I was referring to. That would be the job of the plugin.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried this. I'm about to. It looks quite promising:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/organize-series/

Comment: Hi @Norio & Welcome to WPSE.
Answers consisting of *only* a link without descriptive context are rarely as helpful as they could be. On top of that, be so kind to provide solutions that you actually have tried before.